# Coding buttons to disappear/appear/reset and change color

Tags: javascript

I need some help with coding cause none of what I'm trying is working. **Without using jquery**

I have a start button which upon clicking is supposed to disappear and make another two buttons appear.

One of them being a "End" button and the other is supposed to be a colored box.

**The button that is supposed to be a colored box:**

Default is that it has one color. I did that by simply setting the background color.
It is supposed to change color when clicked. It should be clickable 3 times so that it shows a total of 4 colors.

*E.g.: Button appears-> Green->click->Yellow->click->Red->click->blue*

**End button:**

This one is supposed to set everything back to just seeing the start button to do all of the above again. 
So: click endbutton-> colorbutton and endbutton disappear, start button appears again. Basically like a reset of the page

*please excuse the editing here, I'm new to this.

Tried different things I deleted for not working. One that worked at least in Codepen for one color change of the colored box/button is :

document.getElementById("colorbox").addEventListener("click", function(){this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";});

Comment: please edit your post and add some code to show what you have tried so far. you will get help faster that way.

Comment: So I tried many things and deleted them when they didn't work. Trying that on codepen (see bottom) for example worked in changing the button once. But it won't work in my file. 

document.getElementById("colorbox").addEventListener("click", function(){this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";});

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store the colors and move through the array on each click. 
Here is the fiddle using a div.

https://jsfiddle.net/1ytsh6ue/

```
<div id="colorbox" style="background-color: green">
    test
</div>


<script>
     var colors = ["yellow", "red", "blue"];
     var pos = 0;

     document.getElementById("colorbox").addEventListener("click", function()
     {
         this.style.backgroundColor = colors[pos];
         if (pos < colors.length)
            pos++;
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did really help out

Comment: I wanted to get you something you could use now, but extending this further I would store the "pos" value in a html5 data attribute on the div, so each div has its own incrementor

Answer (score 0):

You can check here below code by runing. [See this code in action](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBM7M0A6QM6V)

> **Note** I made this specially for you so please check it out ☺ and you can do more then that what you need.

```html
<style>
#colorBtn, #endBtn {
transition: all .3s;border: none; width: 30%;padding: 10px 20px;
}
#startBtn {
background: purple;
color:#fff;padding: 10px 20px;border: none;}
#colorBtn {background: green;border:none;color:#fff;}
.hide { visibility :hidden;
opacity :0;
}

.show {
visibility : visible; 
opacity :1;
}
</style>
<button id="startBtn">Start Now</button>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
<button id="colorBtn" class="hide">Color</button>
<button id="endBtn" class="hide">end</button></div>

<br /><br />

<label for="colorPic">Add your Own Color </label><br /><br />
<input type="color" id="colorPic"value="#00000"/>
<script>

let index = 1;
const colors = ["green","yellow", "red", "blue", "purple ","orange","pink"];

const colorPic = document.querySelector("#colorPic");colorPic.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
colors.push(colorPic.value);});


const startBtn = document.querySelector('#startBtn');
const endBtn = document.querySelector('#endBtn'); 
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('#colorBtn');

startBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
index = 0;
colorBtn.style.background = colors[index];

colorBtn.innerHTML = colors[index]
startBtn.classList.add("hide");
endBtn.classList.remove("hide");
endBtn.classList.add("show");colorBtn.classList.add("show");colorBtn.classList.remove("hide");
});

endBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {index = 0;
startBtn.classList.remove("hide");
endBtn.classList.add("hide");
endBtn.classList.remove("show");colorBtn.classList.remove ("show");colorBtn.classList.add ("hide");
});

colorBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{index++;
if (index >= colors.length) {index = 0;}
colorBtn.style.background = colors[index];

colorBtn.innerHTML = colors[index];
});
</script>
```

**Are you trying build a fun game...?☺**

**Thank You**[image]

Comment: Oh my! So much effort. Thank you so much. That helped me make the buttons work as I need them to!